# How do I toggle between items in a FlatList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I added a custom radio button to each of my flatlist items. So there's a radio button on the left of each item row and I want to be able to toggle between the selected value of the radio button depending on row item. So, I can select the first row item and that's selected/toggled on or select the second one item and that's toggled on and the first row item is toggled off.

I'm a bit confused on how to set up the logic for this with my current object. My current object has an id and isSelected bool. The bool will indicate if the row is isSelected or not (i.e. is checked or not).

Here's what i have so far:

This is my component that renders the flatlist fooItems. The fooItems itself is the individual elements that make up the list.

```
export class FooItemsComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        //some reducer action 
      }

    renderItem = item => {
         if (item.load) {
          return <ActivityIndicator color={Colors.activityColor} size="small" />;
        } else {

          return (
              <View>
                <FooItem
                    {...item}
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                    showParticularItems={true}
                />
                </View>
          ); }
      };

    render() {
        const { fooItems, navigation, loading, props} = this.props;
        if (!fooItems) fooItems = [];

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => `key-${index}`}
                data={fooItems}
                renderItem={item => this.renderItem(fooItems.item)}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}
                ListHeaderComponent={Header}
                ListFooterComponent={loading ? LoadingFooter : Separator}
                />
          </View>

        );
    }
}
```

FooItem component:

```
export default class FooItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isSelected: this.props.fooItems.isSelected

    };
  }

  changeSelected = isSelected => {

    if(!isSelected) {
      let selected = this.props.fooItems; 
        selected = selected.isSelected = true; 

        this.setState({ isSelected: selected});
      }
  }; 

  render() {
    const {
      Details,
      showPreferred = false,
      showSetSelected = false, 
      navigation
    } = this.props;

    const { isSelected} = this.state; 

    return (
      <View
        style={[ showSetSelected? styles.setDefaultContainer : 
          styles.container,
          showBorder ? { borderBottomWidth: 1, borderTopWidth: 1 } : {},
        ]}
      >
        {showSetSelected && (
            <View> 
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={[styles.info, !isSelected ? styles.lineBreak : {}]}
                onPress={() => this.changeSelected(isSelected)}
              >
               <RadioButton isChecked={isSelected}></CheckedCircle>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

My custom control:

```
const RadioButton = ({ isChecked  }) => {
    let checkedStatus;
    switch (isChecked) {
      case true:
        checkedStatus = <Image style={styles.container} source={require('../../../assets/radioButton.png')} />
        break
      default:
        checkedStatus = <Image style={styles.container} source={require('../../../assets/circle.png')} />
        break
    }
    return <View style={styles.container}>{checkedStatus}</View>
  }
```

Right now, I'm noticing the other row that is not already selected and I select it, the radio button state for that particular row is checked but now I have two checked/selected rows instead of one. So I want to know how to toggle the other row. How can I get this done?

EDIT:

Example of radio button toggle in a list where I only want to toggle between listed radio buttons between rows of the list.

[image]

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the issue, it will help in better understanding the issue.

Comment: The issue is now whatever radio button I click on is selected, when it should be toggling. The expected behavior is in the example picture above. @bk7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain a state variable such as selectedIndex or some unique id in your `FooItemsComponent` and pass this index/id to each of your FooItem and compare against this selectedIndex as

```
<RadioButton
  isChecked={item.id === this.props.selectedIndex}
/>
```

Maintain a method at FooItemsComponent level which controls which item is checked as follows

```
changeSelected = index => {
    this.setState({
      selectedIndex: index,
    });
};
```

and pass the same to every FooItem

```
<FooItem
  {...item}
  ...
  selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
  changeSelected={this.changeSelected}
/>
```

and finally in the FooItem put this on a Touchable and pass the FooItem's id or index.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.changeSelected(item.id)}>
```

Here is a expo [link](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/toggle-between-items-in-a-flatlist) for rough idea.(Please ignore the styles and make it truly yours!)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one more related question, what if I wanted to have a default value displayed if an item was previously selected? So one of the items is shown selected and then I can toggle it?

Comment: you can try setState in componentDidMount and set the selectedIndex/selectedId value from the data list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of which `FooItem` is selected in the state of your `FooItemsComponent`.
Then use that to check

```
<FooItem
     {...item}
     isSelected={this.state.selectedItem.id === item.id}
     navigation={this.props.navigation}
     showParticularItems={true}
   />
```

Or something in this fashion.

Comment: Can you elaborate on best way to track? Thanks!